# Is there a way to have spaces when creating a data frame in R?

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to create a table pdf using R but first I need to get all my information into a table in R. I wanted to use the read.table function and just add text that way, but there are spaces in my text so it keeps telling me there are too many elements. Is there a way to creating spacing between the words without messing with the table?

This is my code:

```
df<-read.table(text=
"1   data analytic
 2   learn curve
 3   process
 4   competitive"
```

The error that comes up is:
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 2 did not have 4 elements

Answer (score 0):

We can read it with `readLines`, create quotes using `sub` and then read with `read.table`

```
lines1 <- sub("([A-z]+)\\s+([A-z]+)", "'\\1 \\2'", lines)
read.table(text=lines1, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#  V1            V2
#1  1 data analytic
#2  2   learn curve
#3  3       process
#4  4   competitive
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection("1   data analytic
2   learn curve
3   process
4   competitive"))
```

If we are reading from file

```
lines <- readLines("filename.txt")
```